# tempusdominus - allowInputToggle isn't working in Bootstrap 4 project

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using [tempusdominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) and trying to get a property `allowInputToggle` to work: https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/#allowinputtoggle

The purpose of this is that when the user clicks into an `<input>` the calendar should open. As opposed to the default of having to click on the calendar icon.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 (and FontAwesome Pro - latest version, for my icons) and have the following markup:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <label for="date_start" class="mr-2">From</label>
    <div class="input-group date mr-5" id="dateStart" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dateStart" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateStart" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label for="date_end" class="mr-2">To</label>
    <div class="input-group date mr-5" id="dateEnd" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dateEnd" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateEnd" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">View notifications <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

I've initialised tempusdominus as follows:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#dateStart').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
        allowInputToggle: true,
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });

    $('#dateEnd').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
        allowInputToggle: true,
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the calendar icon, I get the calendar:

[image]

But when I click in the input (e.g. `#dateStart`) I don't:

[image]

The purpose of setting `allowInputToggle` to `true` on initialisation is to make this work. So why isn't it doing?

No console errors.

Tried in **browsers:** Firefox 68.0.1 and Chrome 76.0.3809.100. Same behaviour.

**Using:** jquery 3.2.1, moment.js 2.24.0, Bootstrap 4.0.0, Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4 v5.0.0-alpha14

Comment: working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/6ma3rpuz/)

Comment: looks like you're missing a couple files

Comment: @keith such as what?

Comment: just look at User863 files vs yours, theres a bootstrap file you're missing

Answer (score 1):

A little late reply, but we had this same issue recently and found that it wasn't necessary to use the `allowInputToggle` option.

Just add `data-toggle="datetimepicker"` to the input element as well as the div containing the icon.

As [here](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/#no-icon-input-field-only)